# AngularJS use items from ng-init return

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible in AngularJS to return something from ng-init, that is inside an ng-repeat, and then do an ng-repeat with the results? For example if i have

```
<ng-repeat="c in customers">
    <div ng-init="getItems(c)">
         {{object returned from getItems(c)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i access the JSON object that is returned from getItems(c) ?

Comment: It is wiser to use the controller (or a service) to make multiple requests to a server. Using `ng-init` mixes the concerns of the template with that of the controller. It makes the app difficult to understand, debug, test, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways, but I wouldn't use `ng-init` for this. The ng-init doc page says:

> There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit: aliasing special
>   properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. initializing data
>   during development, or for examples, as seen throughout these docs.
>   injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you
>   should use Components or Controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

You could simply go with: `ng-repeat="c in customers.map(cust => getItems(cust))"`

Comment: I have an ng-repeat and inside some (not all) of them there is a second table that would have an ng-repeat but it needs to know the c.id to do a json request for the next ng-repeat. I dont think this works for me?

Comment: Idealy i would do ng-repeat="i in getItems(c.id)"  and then do a json request and return the data but it wont let me return in the success of the ajax request

Comment: In that case, you need to do more work in the controller code. You should not be fetching data inside the view logic, which is meant for rendering only. Iterate over the customer array in the controller and fetch the items from the backend. Assign to some other array in scope, e.g. `customerData`. Then you can change your view loop to `ng-repeat="c in customerData"`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was being so lazy -_-' took longer to write this question than it did to loop through the results and then push an array in the client list. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to do this in your controller as others did. But if you really want to proceed with your current approach you can try the following.

```
<div ng-repeat="c in customers">
    <div ng-init="c.items = getItems(c)">
         {{c.items}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function directly without using ng-init

```
<ng-repeat="c in customers">
    <div>
         {{getItems(c)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.getItems  = function(customer) {
  ....
}
```